# Login button will be Logout button

Tags: javascript, html, logout

I'm just a beginner at HTML and JavaScript and I try to made a Login and sign up page. The user needs to sign up first to be able to login. If a user tries to log in an account that is not registered it will return an error message saying "user not found". (**Note: I made an array where the registered accounts is stored**)

When the user successfully login his/her account the username and password that the user input in the input box will remain and the input box will be a readonly.

**I want to make:**

1. The login button will turn into a Logout button when a user successfully login his/her account.
2. When the user click the logout button his/her account will be logout and the input box will be reset and the user will able to login his/her account again.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="txtUsername">
   </div>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="txtPassword">
</div>
<div class="mt-3 container text-center">
   <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-outline-primary" id="btnLogin">Login</button>
   <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-target="#registerModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" id="btnRegister">Register</button>
</div>
<div class="mt-3 container text-center">
   <a href="#" class="link-dark" data-bs-target="#forgotPassModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" id="btnForgotPass">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function login(username = "", password = "") {

  username = $(`#txtUsername`).val();
  password = $(`#txtPassword`).val();

  let indexOfUser = users.findIndex((u) => {
    return u.username == username && u.password == password && !u.isDeleted;
  });
  
  
  

  if (indexOfUser == -1) {
    return alert(`User not found`);
    
 }

  // Happy path
  $("#txtUsername").val(username).attr('readonly', true);
  $("#txtPassword").val(password).attr('readonly', true);
  user = users[indexOfUser];
  showUsers(indexOfUser);
 
}
```

Comment: This is **not** how we do that kind of stuff. You should discontinue even if you believe this is a *school demo project*. The major issue here is that your javascript seems to search a local array (`users.findIndex`) and compare username/password against this local array. However, authentication should involve a backend server, where usernames are stored in plain text, passwords are one-way hashed and upon succesfull authentication, the server should issue a cookie/a token to distinguish authenticated and anonymous users.

Comment: Also, local state management and conditional rendering in plain javascript can be extremely tedious and error prone. It would be much easier to use a client-side library (angular, react, vue, ...) where components can be rendered depending on a local state.

Comment: You should not handle login/logout functionality client-side. You should do it on a server instead.

Comment: @WiktorZychla he is just now learning HTML and JS as he said, how is he supposed to use a framework and do authentication "the right way" with backend and stuff? He should train and master the basic stuff first

Comment: To make your life easier, one approach is to store a boolean value in a variable called "isLoggedIn". Based off of this variable value display one view when the user is logged in and the other when he is not.

Answer (score 1):

as commented by other users real world login system always involve a backend server, but in your case you can do like this:

- Store the login status of user in a global variable
- Decide what to do: login or logout, plus style the button accordingly

Here's an example:

```
$('#btnLogin').on('click', login);
var loginStatus = false;

function login(username = "", password = "") {
    if (loginStatus) {
        logout();
        return;
    }
    username = $(`#txtUsername`).val();
    password = $(`#txtPassword`).val();

    let indexOfUser = users.findIndex((u) => {
        return u.username == username && u.password == password && !u.isDeleted;
    });




    if (indexOfUser == -1) {
        return alert(`User not found`);

    }


    // Happy path
    loginStatus = true;
    $("#txtUsername").val(username).attr('readonly', true);
    $("#txtPassword").val(password).attr('readonly', true);
    user = users[indexOfUser];
    showUsers(indexOfUser);

    //style login button as logout
    $('#btnLogin').text("Logout");
}

function logout() {
    loginStatus = false;
    $("#txtUsername").val("").attr('readonly', false);
    $("#txtPassword").val("").attr('readonly', false);
    user = null;
    //style logout button as login
    $('#btnLogin').text("Login");
}
```

Comment: @Marcosomefox Thanks for your answer but I try your code but it doesn't clear the textbox I think the function logout is not working

Comment: $("#txtUsername").val("")   this code should clear the input if the html id is correct, you can run it in the console to test it.

$("#txtUsername").length 

should return 1 if the id is correct, 0 if not, 2 or more if there are copies of the input with the same id in you page (bad situation but still it should clear all inputs with that id)